# Scope of variables in callback methods called within for each

Tags: java

In my code block below, will I get the correct link value in the response for the called URL in the async post?

```
for (Link link:links){
       client.post(link.url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() { //async
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
           Log.d("test","Success Post - "+link.url);
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
           Log.d("test","Failed Post"+link.url);
       }
    })      
}
```

Comment: In other words, are you asking is the `link` defined in your enhanced-for going to be the same as the `link` variable you use inside of the anonymous class?  Unless I'm missing something, I imagine it would.  Have you tried to compile and run it?

Comment: Yes exactly...I just wanted to check how java deals with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your anonymous class instance will capture the value the `link` variable had at the time it is created. Therefore you will retrieve the correct value.

Especially note the semantics of *enhanced for* regarding the iteration variable: it is *effectively final*, unlike `int i` in an index-based iteration idiom. The scope of the variable is subtly different in those two cases: whereas the scope of `i` is the whole for-loop, the scope of your `link` variable is just the loop body. This is less than obvious from the syntax because in both cases the variable is declared in the for-loop header.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Consider the case when there is a parallel thread running and changing the values of `url` fields of in your `Link` instances.

Even though the anonymous class captures a correct reference to the `Link` object contained by `link` variable, if `url` field is changed at any of the objects before response comes back, you'll get the changed value.

So it also depends on your application design. If there is no such thread, you're safe.